# When trying to list the consumer groups, i get timeout exception

Tags: apache-kafka, amazon-iam, kafka-consumer-api, aws-msk

i need to list my consumers in my bootstrap server and for that i'm using below command.

```
 .bin/kafka-consumer-groups.sh --bootstrap-server b-2.amazonaws.com:9098,b-3.amazonaws.com:9098,b-1.amazonaws.com:9098 --list --command-config bin/client.properties
```

in my client.properties file i have below code.

```
security.protocol=SASL_SSL
sasl.mechanism=AWS_MSK_IAM
sasl.jaas.config=software.amazon.msk.auth.iam.IAMLoginModule 
sasl.client.callback.handler.class=software.amazon.msk.auth.iam.IAMClientCallbackHandler
```

But when i run the command i get below error. My kafka version is 3.2.0

[image]

I've seen some similar questions like this and answer for that question was to add SSL properties in a separate file and use it in the command. But i'm doing the same thing. But still getting a timeout error.